# JavaScript url redirect based on another text class content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking to create a jQuery url redirect based on filtering the content in the h2 class shown below. So far I have been trying to test with what you see below ::


What I need assistance with is the filtering of the h2 to look for a certain word. Such as, if the h2 class contains the word "Unit," then clicking on the link will redirect to a new webpage, in this case www.link.com. Otherwise, if it does not, it will stay with the default url.com already in the href.

```
<h2 class="unit"> Sample Unit </h2>

<a "href="http://www.url.com" target="_blank"> Sample Link </a>
```

I have seen this solution for the jQuery below, but I haven't been able to filter or edit it to filter the h2 correctly.

```
$(location).attr('href', 'http://www.link.com')
```

Comment: `href="href="http://` two `href`?

Comment: fixed :) quick copy/past error sorry

Comment: you can also use Search -- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about h2 innerHTML try this one

```js
var str = document.getElementsByClassName("unit")[0].innerHTML;
var result = str.indexOf("Unit") > -1;
(result) ? $("a").attr("href", "http://www.link.com/"): $("a").attr("href", "http://www.url.com");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="unit"> Sample Unit </h2>
<a href="http://www.url.com" target="_blank"> Sample Link </a>
```

Comment: Just ran it and it works! The only further hang up I have is possibly not being able to add id's to both link and header. Does JavaScript have a thing against selecting classes?

Comment: yaa you're probably talking about
document.getElementsByClassName("ex");

Comment: Check out! I've updated the code just as you said by using class

Answer (score 0):

Use `jquery's` **[`.contains`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/)** to check if `h2` contains `Unit` as below:

```
var hasUnit=$('h2').contains('Unit'); //returns true or false
```

change the `href` based on above return value.

Answer (score 0):

```
    /* get all "h2" tags with class "unit"
    and loop on each elements it finds in your page */

    $("h2.unit").each(function() {

      /* check each h2.unit if it has "unit" text inside it
      we internally changed to lowercase to make it case insensitive
      if "unit" text does not exists .indexOf("unit") will return -1 */

        if ($(this).html().toLowerCase().indexOf("unit") >= 0) {

          // change its next sibling with "a" tag's href to www.link.com

          $(this).next("a").attr("href", "http://www.link.com");
      }
    });
```

Shortcut suggested by one of the comments.

```
$("h2.unit:contains('unit')").next("a").attr("href", "http://www.link.com");
```

Comment: How about `$(':contains(YOUR_TEXT)')` ?

Comment: Ah thank you! this works very well...event selects just the class name. I came across all of these elements..but putting together is another story.